# How can I change the font size of hackerskeyboard project?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I installed the https://code.google.com/p/hackerskeyboard/ project and I add  the following row to the file 
kbd_full.xml

```
  <Row  >
            <Key
                android:horizontalGap="1.1%p"
                android:keyLabel="GMAIL"
                android:keyOutputText="GMAIL"
                android:keyWidth="10.0%p" />
            <Key
                android:horizontalGap="1.1%p"
                android:keyLabel="Hotmail"
                android:keyOutputText="Hotmail"
                android:keyWidth="19.0%p" />
            <Key
                android:horizontalGap="1.1%p"
                android:keyLabel="YAHOO"
                android:keyOutputText="YAHOO"

                android:keyWidth="19.0%p" />
            <Key
                android:horizontalGap="1.1%p"
                android:keyLabel="LIVE"
                android:keyOutputText="LIVE"
                android:keyWidth="13.185714%p" />
            <Key
                android:horizontalGap="1.1%p"
                android:keyLabel="MAIL"
                android:keyOutputText="MAIL"
                android:keyWidth="13.185714%p" />
            <Key
                android:horizontalGap="1.1%p"
                android:keyLabel="\@"
                android:keyOutputText="\@"
                android:keyWidth="12.185714%p" />
            <Key
                android:horizontalGap="1.1%p"
                android:keyLabel=".COM"
                android:keyOutputText=".COM"
                android:keyWidth="13.185714%p" />
            <Key
                android:horizontalGap="1.1%p"
                android:keyLabel=".CO.UK"
                android:keyOutputText=".CO.UK"
                android:keyWidth="17.0%p" />
            <Key
                android:horizontalGap="1.1%p"
                android:keyLabel=".EU"
                android:keyOutputText=".EU"
                android:keyWidth="13.185714%p" />
            <Key
                android:horizontalGap="1.1%p"
                android:keyLabel="-"
                android:keyOutputText="-"
                android:keyWidth="13.185714%p" />
            <Key
                android:horizontalGap="1.1%p"
                android:keyLabel="_"
                android:keyOutputText="_"
                android:keyWidth="13.185714%p" />
        </Row>
```

but it appear so big so I want to reduce the size of font of this row , I tried to change the attribute  android:labelTextSize="6dp" but no thing happen , How can I reduce the font size in this project ?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to solve my problem

```
 <Row  android:rowEdgeFlags="top"   android:keyHeight="4%p"     android:horizontalGap="1.8%p">
        <Key
             android:codes="300"

            android:keyIcon="@drawable/icon_gmail"
            android:keyOutputText="gmail"
             />
        <Key
            android:codes="301"

             android:keyOutputText="hotmail"
            android:keyIcon="@drawable/icon_hotmail" />
        <Key
             android:codes="302"

            android:keyOutputText="yahoo"
           android:keyIcon="@drawable/icon_yahoo"

            />


      <Key
           android:codes="303"

            android:keyIcon="@drawable/icon_live"
            android:keyOutputText="live"
            />
        <Key
               android:codes="304"

             android:keyIcon="@drawable/icon_mail"
            android:keyOutputText="mail"
           />
        <Key
               android:codes="305"

              android:keyIcon="@drawable/icon_at"
            android:keyOutputText="\@"
           />
        <Key
               android:codes="306"

             android:keyIcon="@drawable/icon_com"
            android:keyOutputText=".com"
            />
        <Key
               android:codes="307"

            android:keyIcon="@drawable/icon_co_uk"
            android:keyOutputText=".co.uk"
            />
        <Key
               android:codes="308"

           android:keyIcon="@drawable/icon_eu"
            android:keyOutputText=".eu"
            />
        <Key
               android:codes="309"

             android:keyIcon="@drawable/icon_dash"
            android:keyOutputText="-"
           />
        <Key
               android:codes="310"

            android:keyIcon="@drawable/icon_underscore"
            android:keyOutputText="_"
            />
     </Row>
```

and there are the icons 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B01ew9ECCvc8eVZYVTVzZVhvNUk/edit?usp=sharing